# Hypothesis testing of mean when the sample is not large & population is not normal

Tags: hypothesis-testing, mean

There is a group of 20 people. The test results show that the sample mean is 650 and the sample standard deviation is 45. I need to test the hypothesis that the university test result mean is 600.

I am confused because the sample is not large and there is no assumption that the population is normal, so generally speaking I cannot apply t-test or z-test.

So, what test can I apply in this case?

Comment: You don't really get a choice of statistic: only the sample mean gives you much information about the hypothesis, so--noting that the standard error of the mean is $45/\sqrt{20}\approx 10,$ the question comes down to deciding whether, *when the sample mean is approximately five standard errors away from the hypothesized mean,* you can reasonably conclude that is significant evidence against the hypothesis.  Are you familiar with Chebyshev's Inequality?

Comment: This read like a homework question, so I've added the [self-study](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/self-study) tag. Please read its [wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Of course, if this isn't in fact homework, you can roll back the change.

Comment: @dipetkov It may be self-study and not actually be homework so it may well need to remain even if not homework. But please also note the very last dot-point under the tag-wiki info https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info